# SharePoint incoming email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs, incoming-email

We had a contractor install important OS patches on our Windows 2012 R2 servers. They ended up letting a handful of SharePoint security patches get through because on two servers, microsoft updates was checked. Now our farm is complaining about missing patches.

I am going to rebuild the two servers that got the SP patches, but the other problem now is incoming email stopped working. It is set up correctly and the emails are showing up in the drop folder and timer job is removing them, but they never show up in the lists.

Anyone ever see this before? There is nothing that I can see in the ULS except an entry saying it processed the incoming emails.

**EDIT**: I looked again in the log files and I found the following:

> Failed to find  tag corresponding to ID "112" for site definition ID "20" language "1033", falling back to global site definition.  e412579e-1657-701d-4c16-8178293a2e06
>
> The schema for field with this name is wrong or missing .  field 'IconOverlay'.   e412579e-1657-701d-4c16-8178293a2e06
>
> The schema for field with this id is wrong or missing.  field '{7d95d1f4-f5fd-4a70-90cd-b35abc9b5bc8}'.   e412579e-1657-701d-4c16-8178293a2e06
>
> The schema for field with this name is wrong or missing .  field 'IconOverlay'.   e412579e-1657-701d-4c16-8178293a2e06
>
> RelativeUrl = /site/subsite/Shared Documents/19366776-2.pdf   e412579e-1657-701d-4c16-8178293a2e06
>
> Entering monitored scope (EnsureListItemsData). Parent Timer Job job-email-delivery   e412579e-1657-701d-4c16-8178293a2e06
>
> Normalization for URL mailto:some-email@email-domain failed. Unknown foreign URL. e412579e-1657-701d-4c16-8178293a2e06
>
> Stack trace: stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000F560E) at 0x00007FF8E442560E OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000001BB87A) at 0x00007FF8E4C7B87A OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000001BB637) at 0x00007FF8E4C7B637 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000001BB006) at 0x00007FF8E4C7B006 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000001BB566) at 0x00007FF8E4C7B566 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000003002CA) at 0x00007FF8E4DC02CA OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000300475) at 0x00007FF8E4DC0475 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002FE9FC) at 0x00007FF8E4DBE9FC OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002F87BF) at 0x00007FF8E4DB87BF OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002F6D54) at 0x00007FF8E4DB6D54 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000001BB1E8) at 0x00007FF8E4C7B1E8 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000001BACD6) at 0x00007FF8E4C7ACD6 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000AB767) at 0x00007FF8E4B6B767 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000A471A) at 0x00007FF8E4B6471A OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000068DD1) at 0x00007FF8E4B28DD1 OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000001576E) at 0x00007FF8E4AD576E Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000008B78D) at 0x00007FF8E570B78D   e412579e-1657-701d-4c16-8178293a2e06

I'll add that the servers that got updated with the SP patches were the stand alone search servers (not the server with incoming email set up). The search databases have the status of: Database is too new and is not supported.

Not sure if incoming email somehow uses search to find a list when processing email.

Comment: Check the uls logs if you "send" a test email (You can copy one into the folder) Check why SP is dismissing the mails based on the logs (might have to bump up the logging levels a bit).

Comment: I looked again in the ULS and found this: "Normalization for URL mailto:username@email-address failed. Unknown foreign URL"

Comment: I opened an incident with MS. I will post the resolution

Comment: got a Case ID ?